# How to remove the space before name of the directory using linux?

Tags: linux

---

Here is my linux command and its generated output:

i gave ls -l to list all the files which gives the following output:

```
dr-xr-xr-x  5 rsa guest  4096 Jul  3 11:23 tsmc_40g_mixsig_7z_0p9v_2p5v
drwxrwxr-x  2 rsa guest  4096 Jul  3 11:33  tsmc_40lp_mixsig_7z_1p1v_2p5v
```

In the above the second line the directory has created with space before the name starts.How can i remove the space before the name of the directory using linux command?

Comment: make use of mv. 
mv " tsmc_40lp_mixsig_7z_1p1v_2p5v" tsmc_40lp_mixsig_7z_1p1v_2p5v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either enclode it in single quotes:
`mv ' tsmc_40g_mixsig_7z_0p9v_2p5v' tsmc_40g_mixsig_7z_0p9v_2p5v`
Or you can use the backslash to escape a space:
`mv \ tsmc_40g_mixsig_7z_0p9v_2p5v tsmc_40g_mixsig_7z_0p9v_2p5v`

In many shells you can use tab completion to make it easier:

`mv ' <TAB>` in many configurations of bash or zsh will turn into: `mv ' tsmc_40g_mixsig_7z_0p9v_2p5v'` though this might not work depending on your configuration. You type `mv` a space a single quote, another space and then you press the tab key and it should show suggestions, where you can then press tab again to complete it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the `rename` utility you could weed out these leading blanks as follows:

```
rename -v '/\S/ and s/^\s+//' ./*
```

where we run the utility on all files in the current dir., and ensure that it has at least one nonwhitepsace and then go ahed and trim the leading whitespace.

The `-v` option wil echo the filenames being mv-ed.

Answer (score 0):

I had tried the below one it works for me.

```
 mv \ tsmc_40lp_mixsig_7z_1p1v_2p5v tsmc_40lp_mixsig_7z_1p1v_2p5v
```